# How does OpenGL know to what position it should draw the vertices based on the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER?

Tags: c++, opengl, buffer, vbo, vao

For example, I have the following piece of code:

```
//Create a vbo and bind it to the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER
glGenBuffers(1, &positionBufferObject);    
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBufferObject);

//vertexPosition is an array of floats that stores the position of 3 vertices (x, y, z, w)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexPositions), vertexPositions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

//Enable the vbo at index 0 of the vao (assuming I have stored it previously at index 0)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

//Finally draw the triangle
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

My question is, how does glDrawArrays() know that whatever is bound to the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER refers to information about position, and not about colors for example?

Comment: It doesn't.   But your shader does and the two are bound together.

Comment: The thing is I was able to draw a triangle with that code without using shaders. That's why I'm confused.

Comment: I don't know the driver details, but I expect there's some kind of default, whereby the primitive assumes it's a position component first.

Comment: @Robinson: Each driver may have their own, but NVidia is pretty consistent about it. https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/ClockworkCoders/attributes.php

Comment: Generally, using generic vertex attributes without a shader is asking for trouble. Often times, attribute 0 seems to be aliased with the fixed function position. But that's **not** going to work on all platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where `gl_Vertex` is available (ie not a core profile), the specification calls out that position and vertex attribute 0 alias.

From the [gl 4.5 compatibility profile specification](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec45.compatibility.pdf) (page 401/1005):

> Setting  generic  vertex  attribute  zero  specifies  a  vertex,  as 
>   described  in  section 10.7.2. Setting any other generic vertex
>   attribute updates the current values of the attribute. There are no
>   current values for vertex attribute zero